# How to visualize model data in different ways in QTableView?

Tags: qt

I have a model containing in one column floats (ex: 22.7). Now, I want that 
in QTableView, it will be visualized together with the unit (MB): 22.7 MB.
The reason I am doing so is because I want that sorting is based on floats, but
the visualization is as I said with units.

I created a Model, a Filter and a View. But it does not work. Here is a piece of my code:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel *filterModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(0);
filterModel->setSourceModel(model);

QStandardItem* vSItem6 = new QStandardItem();
vSItem6->setData(22.7, Qt::DisplayRole); 
model->setItem(1, 7, vSItem6);
QModelIndex index = model->index(1, 7, QModelIndex());
QString itext = model->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString(); 
filterModel->setData(index, itext + " MB", Qt::DisplayRole);


mUi.tableView->setModel(filterModel);
mUi.tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
mUi.tableView->show();
```

Everything seems to be fine, but in QTableView, only the float number is visualized (without the unit MB). Can anybody please help me? Thanks

Comment: When posting code, select it and press the 101010 button to make it look like code, it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [setItemDelegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) or setItemDelegateForColumn. You can derive your delegate class from QStyledItemDelegate, and in the overridden paint method you can paint your numbers including the units.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But I still don't understand why to use model view controller widgets if even simple things don't work. I heard somewhere that proxy model should help, but there is no example around...

Comment: @Tom: The delegate classes are helpers to fix how individual items are drawn.  Since you want to change how the item is drawn, the delegate class makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie in Qt development, but can't you derive from class `QAbstactTableModel`, and implement the `data` method so that it returns the float value plus "MB" (in a QString object), when role is `DisplayRole`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to take the value of the model and modify it's string representation you can do so easily by inheriting from QStyledItemDelegate and just overriding a single method namely displayText(), which returns a QString. I just did that to have the values (representing the amount of memory consumed by a process) displayed in the most appropriate unit (byte, kbyte, megabyte and so on). So it's a usecase that is more or less similar to the problem described above and it works like a charme. You can see the code below (but ignore the application specific parts).

Header file:

```
#pragma once 

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class UnitAwareItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UnitAwareItemDelegate(QObject* parent = 0);
    virtual QString displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const;
};
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "UnitAwareItemDelegate.hpp"
#include "UnitUtils.hpp"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionViewItem>
#include <QModelIndex>

UnitAwareItemDelegate::UnitAwareItemDelegate(QObject* parent): QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QString UnitAwareItemDelegate::displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale& locale) const
{
    if (value == 0)
    return QString();

    // value supplied by libproc is in kb so we mul by 1024 to get the byte value
    uint64_t oldValue = value.toULongLong() * 1024;
    const UnitUtils::ValueUnit unit = UnitUtils::findSuitableUnit(oldValue);
    const uint64_t newValue = oldValue / UnitUtils::value(unit);

    return QString("%1 %2")
    .arg(QString::number(newValue))
    .arg(QString(UnitUtils::name(unit).at(0)).toUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your question was about QTableView, but it might be easier if it is the only thing you want to display (I don't know your objectives) to use a QTableWidget with a QDoubleSpinBox since it has a method that allows you to set a suffix to the value that is displayed.

In your case, it would be:

```
QDoubleSpinBox* spin = new QDoubleSpinBox();
spin->setSuffix("MB");
```

Note that the range is set by default from 0.0 to 99.99 so if you want to set other values you should change the range before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what I am searching for.

Comment: I am using QTableView instead of QTableWidget because of the Model View Controller.

Comment: It would be possible to add another column besides with the unit, but it is clearly not the best solution.

Comment: You could look into setData and specify a DisplayRole (with the MB appended manually after) and a custom role you create to keep your value in a double format.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but it looks stupid. Besides, I have many columns with units... I am surprised that there is nothing in the qt documentation that could help. I mean, everybody is writing how beatyfull model view controller approach is, that you have one model and many views, but nobody gives a useful example of how to do it...